# Results of piping and executing commands consecutively are different?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, command-line

I'm new to bash so apologies if this is dumb.

I'm following [this](https://cameronnokes.com/blog/how-to-convert-heic-image-files-to-jpg-in-bash-on-macos/) guide for converting HEIC images to JPG, and am confused why running `find` and `wc` consecutively yields different results from piping the result of `find` to `wc`. Specifically, for

```
temp=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.HEIC")
count=$(wc -l $temp)
```

`$count` evaluates to a list of files with their word counts, as I would expect. However, if I write it like in the article:

`count=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.HEIC" | wc -l)`

then it evaluates to the count of files with the .HEIC extension.

Comment: You don't actually say which result you want. They are both valid. To actually combine the two steps, use: `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.HEIC" -exec wc -l {} +`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant aren't those heic files binary images? what would counting lines in them would do? That being said, the example from that blog is pretty dumb, because it's using find & stuff to count the number of files, but then it's calling `mogrify` with just a simple `*.HEIC` glob ;-) All that could've been much simpler written as `mogr(){ echo "converting $# files"; magic mogrify ... "$@";  }; mogr *.HEIC`

Comment: @user414777 I just commented on how to do the two-part process in one command (which also solves the lack of quotes and funny filenames in `wc -l $temp`. Why this process would be of any use is another matter. I also see people asking why `wc -l myExcel.xlsx` does not correctly count the rows in their spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

from '[man wc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wc)'

> wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> Print  newline,  word,  and  byte counts for
> each FILE, and a total line if more than one FILE is specified.

```
count=$(wc -l $temp)
```

evaluates to

```
count=$(wc -l /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2 )
```

so it counts lines in all files instead of number of files.
you should change your second line to

```
count=$(echo "$temp" | wc -l)
```

Comment: temp=$(.…) trims all trailing newlines, while echo adds just one, so the answer given this way might still differ. echo can also do weird things if temp starts with a dash

Answer (score 0):

Because bash is not PowerShell (or whatever, I don't know), and `left | right` does not result in `right` being called with the lines or words output by `left` as command line arguments, but in `right` being run with its stdin redirected from a pipe where `left` is writing its output. `left` and `right` will also be run at the same time, not sequentially.

When `wc -l` is invoked without any `files` arguments, it just counts the lines from its stdin. `seq 1 2 | wc -l` will print `2`.

In any case, `find . ... | wc -l` could be easily broken by file names containing newlines, which are (unfortunately) very much allowed. With GNU find, you can work that around with:

```
count=$(find . ... -name '*.HEIC' -printf _ | wc -c)

# or just
count=$(find . ... -name '*.HEIC' -printf _); count=${#count}
```

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that `$(…)` trims off all the trailing newlines, and echo adds a newline, so the answer given by the two methods can differ if the output from `find` ends with blank lines, or if it's completely empty.

In particular, `$( echo "$temp" | wc -l )` will never be 0.